# When i flash a new custom rom, does it get rid of other things that i've flashed before?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, motorola-moto-g

I have a rooted Moto G 2014 and im thinking of flashing a new custom rom on it. It is currently running PacMan Rom and i have Xposed and Google Apps(gapps) flashed right now. I know that flashing a new rom will get rid of all my data, but will i lose gapps and xposed too? Also, does anyone know any good roms?
Thanks

Comment: Flashing a new ROM is not going to wipe your data but only the system, including xposed, custom kernel and GApps.

Answer (score 2):

As of Lollipop all custom ROMs have transitioned to the new `system.new.dat + system.transfer.list` format, so the `/system` partition will be fully overwritten, which means bye bye GAPPS and Xposed. If you migrate to a different ROM, you'll also need to wipe `/data` (not including `/data/media` which is your internal storage).

Then again, flashing GAPPS/Xposed again isn't that hard, is it?

As for ROM recommendation, I think it's against SE's rule to do that here (XDA wouldn't allow that either), so better go try everything yourself. I myself am a die-hard CM fan.